# Laravel HasMany relation on JSON column with plain IDs Array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've tried to setup a *JSON HasMany* relation using the well-known https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations package, on a **plain array of IDs** relating to another *Model*, but with no luck so far.

Basically, I'm trying to relate `RecurringOrder` with `Transaction` *Model* through a dedicated `transaction_ids` column on `recurring_orders` table. Below an extremely simplified example of table structures.

**recurring_orders** table (simplified)

| id | status | valid_from | user_id | valid_to | transaction_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACTIVE | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | [1,4,6] |
| 2 | PENDING | 2023-01-01 | 1 | null |  |

**transactions** table (simplified)

| id | identifier | payment_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | order-recurring | PAID | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | order-alpha | PAID | 2020-06-01 |
| 3 | order-recurring | PROBLEM | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | order-recurring | PAID | 2021-01-01 |
| 5 | order-beta | PAID | 2021-06-01 |
| 6 | order-recurring | PAID | 2022-01-01 |

I'd like to know how to make this work **without a `morph` relation** on `Transactions` and without a **dedicated pivot table** that relates different *types* of *Orders* with their *Transaction* counterpart. As you can see, a *Transaction* can have multiple *types* of *Orders*. A simple `order_id` on `transactions` table would not be correct.

I'd like to make this work so that I can use *Eager Loading* on the *Model* that contains the **plain array of IDs** on `transaction_ids` like:

```
<?php

$recurringOrder = RecurringOrder::with(['transactions', 'other', 'relations'])->where(...)->...;
```

The problems I'm facing are:

1. with `staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations`: I can't find any example related to a **plain array of IDs**
2. tried to implement my very own *Trait*, using `staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations` as a base of reference, but with no success
3. cannot create a relation using a *raw query*. Only thing I can do easily is an accessor with a custom `json_decode`, but that is incompatible with eager loading.

Comment: why do you need the `transaction_ids` column? why not use morph relationship `return $this->morphMany(Transaction::class, 'orderable');`?

Comment: @RawSlugs you're absolutely right, thank you for your contribution. I completely missed that the relation can be obtained through the `Transaction` model itself. Thenk you! I'm modifying the original question anyway, because I'm interested in how to achieve the goal in a different example scenario.

Comment: i just want to clarify so I can try and answer:
There are two models: recurring_orders and transactions and the foreign key is transaction_id which is the id of the transaction
or you're saying that transaction_ids is the array and there are no foreign keys?

Comment: @PhantomPhreak1995 yes, no FK, only `transaction_ids` as plain IDs array in the form `[1,2,3,4,....]`, representing all the `Transactions` of the `RecurringOrder`

Comment: I gotta think about it, will post an answer later on today. In the meanwhile, consider just adding order_id to the transactions? I don't know what you're losing by adding a simple column that would define transactions for the orders (since more transactions can be for the same order? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations: I can't find any example related to a plain array of IDs

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations?tab=readme-ov-file#array-of-ids

```php
class RecurringOrder extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
        'valid_from' => 'date',
        'valid_to' => 'date',
        'transaction_ids' => 'array',
    ];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(Transaction::class, 'transaction_ids');
    }
}
```

```php
class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'date' => 'date',
    ];
}
```

```php
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('identifier');
            $table->enum('payment_status', ['Paid', 'Problem']);
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('recurring_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('status', ['Active', 'Pending']);
            $table->date('valid_from');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->date('valid_to')->nullable();
            $table->json('transaction_ids')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
};
```

```php
RecurringOrder::with("transactions")->get();

/* Output: */
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2798
    all: [
      App\Models\RecurringOrder {#3423
        id: 1,
        status: "Active",
        valid_from: "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
        user_id: 1,
        valid_to: "2023-01-01 00:00:00",
        transaction_ids: "[1,4,6]",
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        transactions: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3429
          all: [
            App\Models\Transaction {#3431
              id: 1,
              identifier: "order-recurring",
              payment_status: "Paid",
              date: "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
              created_at: null,
              updated_at: null,
            },
            App\Models\Transaction {#3434
              id: 4,
              identifier: "order-recurring",
              payment_status: "Paid",
              date: "2021-01-01 00:00:00",
              created_at: null,
              updated_at: null,
            },
            App\Models\Transaction {#3436
              id: 6,
              identifier: "order-recurring",
              payment_status: "Paid",
              date: "2022-01-01 00:00:00",
              created_at: null,
              updated_at: null,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      App\Models\RecurringOrder {#3426
        id: 2,
        status: "Pending",
        valid_from: "2023-01-01 00:00:00",
        user_id: 1,
        valid_to: null,
        transaction_ids: null,
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        transactions: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3428
          all: [],
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```